# iteration problem

Tags: java

I have to iterate through a list `error.getGE.getList` returns me a arraylist of type GE a bean,how to iterate over this list ?

Answer (score 8):

```
for (GE bean: error.getGE().getList()){
   // do something with GE
}
```

This construct is called the For-Each-Loop, and has been available since Java5.

Comment: Information on the minimum Java version and how to pronounce this construct would see a +1 from me :)

Comment: @Arnaud @Grundlefleck The question says *arraylist of type GE*, so it is probably safe to assume it is Java 5 or above. Actually, after more than 5 years of Java 5 I think it's in general best not to suggest pre-5 ways of doing things in Java, unless the question is specifically about legacy Java systems.

Comment: @Fabian: Good point, I overlooked the mention of type which does negate the need for version info. But I reckon there's still way more than enough people stuck on pre Java-5 to warrant the briefest of mentions. And I still think info on how to pronounce this would still be helpful - makes it much easier to search for also.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the size of any ArrayList (independent of the JavaVersion) with .size();
With that information you should be able to loop throu the list:

```
for(int i = 0; i < error.getGE().getList().size(); i++) {
    GE myGe = (GE) error.getGE().getList().get(i);
    // do some stuff with myGe
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instance variable for iterator is generated.... i.e 
Iterator itr=error.getGE().getList().iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
GE value=(GE)itr.next();

// get the required output using 'value'

}